# How to display a grid item's container on mouse hover inside interactive dashboard?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid, gridstack

Last couple days I've been trying to create an interactive dashboard system to display various widgets. I'm trying to achieve behavior where user could see position of the grid item while hovering the mouse over grid container. So far I couldn't find any library that would have such a functionality (tried gridstackjs and gridster). Maybe you know a library that would allow me to achieve such functionality?

So far I've tried to create a basic grid and give items fixed width and height and use mouse over event with some styling to achieve it, but I wonder if there's any library that would help me out. For better understanding I've added a screenshot of a functionality that I'm trying to achieve.
[image: Wanted functionality]